# Local variables not valid in the callback, while some others are

Tags: javascript, closures

I tried to write a small code to download many files (in this example: one .json and one .svg file) and I stumbled into some code I don't understand. I promise, next time I use a Promise, nonetheless, here is the code :

```
var path_name = "some/path/to/go";
var item_name = "some_item_to_get";
var load_lst = [
    [server_get_json, "/cdn/json/?m={0}&q={1}".format(path_name, item_name), "m_json", false],
    [server_get_svg, "/cdn/svg/?m={0}&q={1}".format(path_name, item_name), "m_svg", false],
];

var bucket = new Object;
```

Then I use the following snippet to launch all the downloads, store the result in the bucket and set a flag to `true`.

```
for (let i=0 ; i<load_lst.length ; i++) {
    load_lst[i][0](load_lst[i][1], (obj) => {
        console.log(i, load_lst[i][0], load_lst[i][1], load_lst[i][2]);
        bucket[load_lst[i][2]] = obj;
        load_lst[i][3] = true;
    });
}
```

which logs

```
1 function server_get_svg() /cdn/svg/?m=some/path/to/go&q=some_item_to_get m_svg
0 function server_get_json() /csn/json/?m=some/path/to/go&q=some_item_to_get m_json
```

which is perfectly fine. But the following one does not work at all... the same function is called twice and, generally speaking, my vars are all mixed up.

```
for (let i=0 ; i<load_lst.length ; i++) {
    var [func, url, name, status] = load_lst[i];
    func(url, (obj) => {
        console.log(func, url, name);
        bucket[name] = obj;
        load_lst[i][3] = true;
        console.log(func, url, name, load_lst[0][3], load_lst[1][3]);
    });
}
```

which logs :

```
function server_get_svg() /cdn/svg/?m=some/path/to/go&q=some_item_to_get m_svg false true
function server_get_svg() /cdn/svg/?m=some/path/to/go&q=some_item_to_get m_svg true true
```

I don't understand why the local variable `i` is correctly known in the following anonymous callback, and why `load_lst[i]` works perfectly fine, but `func`, `url`, `name`, `status` do not.
If fact, if I may understand why the second doesn't work, I don't understand why the first one does :)

Comment: The dupe target is correct. In your case it's not a problem with `var i` (you already use `let i`) but `var [func, url, name, status]`. Use `let`.

Comment: let solve the issue (-_-)